# Selecting and changing multiple CSS classes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a twitter bootstrap carousel component and I want to detect it's slide function, through that, foreground color of another component should be changed at each slide move.

```
$('#welcomeCarousel').on('slide',function(e){
   var index = $(this).find('.active').index();       
   if(index==1) {
   $('.navbar-inverse .brand:hover,
      .navbar-inverse .nav > li > a:hover,
      .navbar-inverse .brand:focus,
      .navbar-inverse .nav > li > a:focus').css('color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
   }
});
```

I think problem occurs because of selecting multiple CSS classes, there should be sth. wrong about it because index has correct value. JS console says `unexpected token` or `unexpected string`.

[jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yaapK/10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quicker way to do it, first of all, I've defined another CSS class:

```
.newClass .brand:hover,
.newClass .nav > li > a:hover,
.newClass .brand:focus,
.newClass .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Then, it is easy to toggle or remove this class:

```
if(index==1) {
    $('#myNavigationBar').toggleClass("newClass");
}
if(index==0) {
    $('#myNavigationBar').removeClass("newClass");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this syntax:

```
.css({'color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

Comment: Still throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Answer (score 0):

```
.css('color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
```

Should be:

```
.css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
```

Had you wanted to change multiple css properties, you use this syntax:

```
.css({'color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', diffrentProp : 'SomeValue'});
```

Comment: Still throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı. OH God! You didn't concate the stings in those multiple lines! check out your selector!

Comment: OH God! even that throws `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover`

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı, Create a jsFiddle.

Comment: I've created check question.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı, You know, the error quite says what is the problem. `:hover` [selector is not supported](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (it's not in the list), anyway I'm going to sleep. good luck with what you're trying to do, and please get rid of Recep Tayyip Erdoğan...

Comment: thanks we are trying.. there is no one like Atatürk unfortunately.. Code is not urgent, thanks anyway..